# JAVA Trivia Game Array outside scope

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I know the problem is that the compiler says there is an error with the `qArray` part of where the game is actually played in the code there is a comment that says play the game. I think it's that the scope of `qArray` is outside the loop that uses it but I'm not sure how to get the data from the `intQuestions` method up to where it needs to be in the way I'm using it. Or should I be putting the questions array where the `qArray` is @?

The desired output is to have the `intQuestions` method called on then the data passed into the array used in the for loop where the comment says play the game! I understand the scope of `qArray` is outside but how would I pass the data from the array up to where it says play the game and in the way I'm using it?

```
 public class TriviaGame {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {

     // Constants
     final int NUM_QUESTIONS = 10;
     final int NUM_PLAYERS = 2;


     // Variables
     int playerTurn = 1; // The current player
     int questionNum; // The current question number
     int playerAnswer; // The player's chosen answer
     int player1points = 0; // Player 1's points
     int player2points = 0; // Player 2's points


     // Create an array of Player objects for player #1 and player #2.
     Player[] players = new Player[NUM_PLAYERS];

     for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++)

     {

        players[i] = new Player(i+1);

     }


     // Create an array to hold Question objects.
     Question[] questions = new Question [NUM_QUESTIONS];


     // Initialize the array with data.
     intQuestions(questions);


     // Play the game.
     for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++)

     {
        // Display the question.
        TriviaGame.displayQuestion(qArray[i], playerTurn);


        // Get the player's answer.
        players[playerTurn - 1].chooseAnswer();


        // See if the correct answer was chosen.
        if (qArray[i].getCorrectAnswerNumber() == players[playerTurn - 1].getCurrentAnswer())

        {

            players[playerTurn -1].incrementPoints();

        }


        // See if the the player chose the wrong answer.
        // do nothing
        // Switch players for the next iteration.

        if (playerTurn == 1)

            playerTurn = 2;

        else

            playerTurn = 1;

     }

     // Show the game results.
     showGameResults(players);
 }

 /**

 * The intQuestions method uses the contents of the trivia.txt file to

 * populate the qArray parameter with Question objects.

 */

 public static void intQuestions(Question qArray[]) throws IOException
 {

   // Open the trivia.txt file.

   File file = new File("trivia.txt");

   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


   // Populate the qArray with data from the file.
   for (int i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++)

   {

     // Create a Question object in the array.
     qArray[i] = new Question();


     // Get the question text from the file.
    qArray[i].setQuestion(inputFile.nextLine());


    // Get the possible answers.
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)

    {

       qArray[i].setPossibleAnswer(inputFile.nextLine(), j);

    }

    // Get the correct answer.
    qArray[i].setCorrectAnswerNumber(Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()));

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `questions` instead of `qArray` in `main()` method: `qArray` is visible only inside `intQuestions()` method. When you invoke `intQuestions()` method with parameter `questions` you pass the array to the method and make some initialization to it. After the method `intQuestions()` completes your `questions` array will be initialized with some values.